# Google CALDAV ignoring filter options

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, caldav

Is there any documentation why does the google caldav  api ignores this request.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C:calendar-query xmlns:d="DAV:" 
  xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" 
  xmlns:A="http:/    /apple.com/ns/ical/">
  <d:prop>
    <d:getetag/>
    <C:calendar-data/>
  </d:prop>
  <C:filter>
    <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
      <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
        <C:prop-filter name="UID">
          <C:text-match collation="i;octet">xxxxxxxxxxxx</C:text-match>
        </C:prop-filter>
      </C:comp-filter>
    </C:comp-filter>
  </C:filter>
</C:calendar-query>
```

It returns every event but it should return only the one i requested in the filter.

I can only filter the events with

```xml
<C:time-range start="20160326T230000Z" end="20160430T220000Z"/>
```

but everything else is just ignored.

Comment: Quite likely it just doesn't implement this filter. Maybe elaborate on why you are doing a lookup like that. Don't you already have a URL<->UID map?

Comment: You should try it removing the **collation="i;octet"** attribute. It may be that the server doesn't support this collaction (it's required but well..).

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution to get only one event by uid with caldav api google.

I use href url of the event like $href="https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/**IDCalendar**/events/**uid.**ics

And i query with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<C:calendar-multiget xmlns="DAV:"mlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
<prop><getetag/><C:calendar-data/></prop>
<href>$href</href>
</C:calendar-multiget>
```

and i get only the event with UID :) .

Dam

Answer (score 0):

but Google CalDAV supports calendar-multiget, where you can use same url pattern

https://icalendar.org/CalDAV-Access-RFC-4791/7-9-caldav-calendar-multiget-report.html

Example:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<C:calendar-multiget xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:CS="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" xmlns:D="DAV" xmlns:I="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">
  <ns0:prop xmlns:ns0="DAV:">
  <ns0:getetag/>
  <C:calendar-data/>
  </ns0:prop>

  <ns0:href xmlns:ns0="DAV:">/caldav/v2/[calendar_id]/events/[UID]</ns0:href>

</C:calendar-multiget>
```

with response

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:caldav="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" xmlns:ical="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">
 <D:response xmlns:carddav="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cm="http://cal.me.com/_namespace/" xmlns:md="urn:mobileme:davservices">
  <D:href>/caldav/v2/[calendarID]/events/[UID]</D:href>
  <D:propstat>
   <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
   <D:prop>
    <D:getetag>"63701474571"</D:getetag>
    <caldav:calendar-data>BEGIN:VCALENDAR
.....
</caldav:calendar-data>
   </D:prop>
  </D:propstat>
 </D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```